# Why does this code using fork() work?

Tags: c, fork

I've this code that executes some code depending of if the active process is the parent or the child process in an infinite loop:

```
pid_t childPID;

childPID=fork();

while (1)
{
    if (childPID >=0)
    {
        if (childPID==0)
        {
            [do child process stuff]
        }   
        else
        {
            [do parent process stuff]
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n Fork failed, quitting!!!!!\n");
        return 1;   
    }
 }
```

Code is simple but there's one very big thing on it for me which I don't understand how it happens although I have a guess:

If not taking into consideration that we're creating 2 processes it looks like childPid is constantly being reasigned which I don't think makes any sense.

So my guess, is that fork creates a childPid for each process, returning a 0 to the parent process and the pid to the child process, even though this syntax makes me think it should only return only one result and assign it to chilPid.

Is my guess correct or is there some other thing involved?

Thank you.

Comment: How do `[do parent stuff]` and `[do child stuff]` end? Does either of them exit the program?

Comment: `man fork`, return value: "On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent, and 0 is returned in the child. On failure, -1 is returned in the parent, no child process is created, and errno is set appropriately. "

Comment: "constantly being reasigned" - I only see one assignment to `childPid` in this code, and its *not* in a while-loop

Comment: You're not _creating_ 2 processes. You already have 1 process. You're _cloning_ that process when you call `fork()`. The cloned process is _exactly the same_ as the parent process (who called fork()). Both processes return from fork(); the parent process has the PID returned, while the child process has 0 returned (you then call `getpid()` to get your new pid).

Comment: "*So my guess, is that ...*" don't guess, but **read** (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html) and know.

Answer (score 2):

> So my guess, is that fork creates a childPid for each process, returning a 0 to the parent process and the pid to the child process, even though this syntax makes me think it should only return only one result and assign it to chilPid.

Exactly that. From the fork reference manual:

> > **RETURN VALUE:**
> >            On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent, and
> >            0 is returned in the child.  On failure, -1 is returned in the  parent,
> >            no child process is created, and errno is set appropriately.

so

> Is my guess

Why guess if this is precisely defined in the POSIX specification?

Comment: I had read that, but as I see the code I think that its returns doesn't mean that it assigns to a variable defined in the first process, from my point of view that description could also create 2 new variables that could be accessed with a syntax like [parent_process].childPID or [chil_process].childPid, so you could refer to each one whenever needed and not just access childPid without knowing beforehand if it refers to the parent or child process.

Comment: @user2638180: After a sucessfull `fork` there's a neraly perfect copy of the original process running and both parent and child are in the very same state. But their memory images are different ones. If a return of a PID pair was made it would be impossible for either process to tell if it were parent or child. Hence a slight, but significant asymmetry is required. And this is implemented by returning different values to parent and child. A process can query its PID with `getpid()`, so the child sees a `fork()` returning and the parent the child PID. This introduces the required asymmetry.

Answer (score 1):

From [fork(2) linux man page](http://fork(2)%20Linux%20man%20page:):

> On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent, and 0 is returned in the child.  On failure, -1 is returned in the parent, no child process is created, and errno is set appropriately

So childPID is 0 in the child process and is child's pid in parent's process

Answer (score 1):

What `fork` does is to create a new copy of the actual process to be the child process.

The `childPID=fork();` is evalueated in both processes and it returns one and only one value, the trick is that the value is different depending on which of the process is executed. On the parent process it returns the PID of the new process (child), and on the child process returns `0`, if `fork` wasn't succesful returns `-1` adn the child process is never created